# Apache Nifi: is it possible that a database will be updated automatically when an excel file will be updated?

Tags: apache-nifi

is the following Scenario possible with Nifi?
A database will be updated automatically, when an excel file (xlsx) will be updated. The database will be updated with the new values from the excel file.
The trigger should work when existing rows will get new values or new rows will be added.
If not do you know a other free etl tool that can handle this Scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ListFile procesor for this task.

The ListFile  proc keeps track of **Name,Size,Last modified timestamp**.

Every time ths file changes you will get a flow generated and trigger you .xlsx processing.

The automatic DB update would have to done by a combination of **ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor >> PutSQL** (and place your logic there)